# View Pager - get pager number for each page

Tags: android, android-fragments, indexing, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a fragment that holds a view pager. 
Each page of the view pager contains a fragment.

Is there a possibility to get the index numbers of the current pages 
inside of the content fragment?

Or do I have to pass each fragment its number on creation?

Or do I have to use a static "newInstance" method of the fragment to pass it the data?

Comment: Using setArgument to fragment you can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your view pager/child fragments using **Static factory methods**

```
 private String fragmentId= "";

 /**
   * The argument keys for creating a fragment.
  */
 private static final String ARG_ONE = "arg1";

 /**
   * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment with the given arguments.
  */
  public static MyFragment create(String fragmentId) {
            MyFragment tab = new MyFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
            bundle.putString(ARG_ONE, fragmentId);
            tab.setArguments(bundle);
            return tab;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_home_screen, container, false);
        this.fragmentId=getArguments().getString(ARG_ONE);
        return view;
     }
```

Later you can use the `fragmentId` for knowing the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a tag to your fragment or set a tag to any of your view object of fragment and get in inside your fragment